# Update Javascript source from backbean JSF

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have Javscript in my XHTML file as

```
<script src="test1.js"></script>
```

Now I have couple of other javascripts as well. They are actually themes.

I want give users flexibility to change the them (javascript name) frmo drop-down box .

I tried this way

```
<script src="#{testBean.jsName}</script>
```

Since it is going to be an Ajax update so I have update the section and I updated with

```
<h:panelGrid id="jsName">
<script src="#{testBean.jsName}</script>
</h:panelGrid>
```

This is not inside the form .

when I try

```
    <p:commandButton value="Generate"

actionListener="#{tBean.generateGraph}" update="jsName"></p:commandButton>
```

It doesn't work as it says that it couldn't find `jsName`.

I put that gride inside the form then it wont throw the error but the script name would still remain the same.

Does anyone have better idea or any other way to achieve it?

Comment: I guess that the typos (script-tag and double quotes not closed) are not in your actual project.

Comment: If you want to swith themes, have tried looking at the primefaces ThemeSwitcher? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/themeswitcher.jsf

Comment: @EmilKaminski I am not talking about changing Primefaces Theme.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reference components in JSF ajax? Cannot find component with identifier "foo" in view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to update it from a component inside the form you have to use the absolute id of the panelGrid otherwise primefaces will try to update something with id `jsName` inside the form. When you want to use the absolute id you have to preced a `:`. So try the following for the button:

```
<p:commandButton value="Generate" actionListener="#{tBean.generateGraph}" update=":jsName"/>
```

Comment: Even though it doesn't really solve my problem but still you it has solved some problems.I will accept this an answer.